# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Inventario {
    public static ArrayList<Vehiculo> listInv = new ArrayList<Vehiculo>();
    public static void agregarVehiculo(Vehiculo i){
        listInv.add(i);
    }
    public static void procesarComandos(Scanner sc){
        boolean flag= true;
        while(flag){
            String[] opcion= sc.nextLine().split("&"); //El nextLine hace que tome todo dado que hay una parte que tiene un espacio, sin el se perderian datos
            switch(opcion[0]){
                case "3":
                    flag = false;
                    break; //siempre hay que ponerlo para que rompa
                case "2":
                    //Impresion
                    System.out.println("***Inventario de vehículos***");
                    for(Vehiculo i: listInv){
                        System.out.println(i.toString());
                        break;
        }
                case "1":
                    switch(opcion[1]){
                        case "Comercial":
                            agregarVehiculo(new Comercial(opcion[1], Integer.parseInt(opcion[2]), Integer.parseInt(opcion[3]), opcion[4], Integer.parseInt(opcion[5])));
                            break;
                        case "Particular":
                            agregarVehiculo(new Particular(opcion[1], Integer.parseInt(opcion[2]), Integer.parseInt(opcion[3]), opcion[4], opcion[5]));
                            break;
                //default es igual al else
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Tipo de vehiculo no aceptado");
            }
        }
    }
}  
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       procesarComandos(sc);        
   } 
}
```

Este es el codigo, el error me menciona la ultima linea y la linea donde comienzo el switch para agregar los vehiculos. Ya intente mirando identacion o mirando el for que es donde generaalmente se da este problema, pero no hallo donde estoy cometiendo el error.

Comment: Puedes agregar un ejemplo de la línea que lee el escáner?

Comment: Claro que si, seria como "1&Particular&8&160&EEE 111&Verde", y al imprimir, me muestra el primero que ingrese, pero para el segundo ya da el error

Comment: El problema era el break que estaba dentro del for, leccion aprendida!